# button to specific ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am just trying to navigate to my 3rd ViewController from a UIButton but I am not sure how to call it. I know how to call back and root ViewController but not to a specific "IBThirdViewController". Was not sure if I could do something like this and call it by name

```
- (IBAction)tourButton:(id)sender {

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:IBTHirdViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: If pushing directly is applicable for your app  (by that I mean, any reason why not using a push segue?) then you have to have an object to push. You don't have an object you just have a name. Create an IBTHirdViewController and push that and see if it works, if not time for a new question

Comment: this button is in pop up with its own xib file so was not sure how to do a segue since they are on 2 different story boards

Comment: Ok. try what I said then (P.S. you shouldn't have two different storyboards if that wasn't a typo, you can have multiple xibs or a storyboard in combination with xibs. But multiple storyboards, while a solution in some situations, is probably not what you want)

Comment: Sorry I have multiple XIBs not storyboards. I already have the created the IBThirdViewController but inside the button I get an error of Undeclared Identifier.

Comment: Post your latest code

Answer (score 0):

If you have button on the popup view you should create block or delegate. So suppose controllerA has pop up with controllerB. As I understood your controllerB is a pop up and it contains button with handler `- tourButton`.

In this case you should add delegate to your controllerB. So I am not sure about your names of classes and structure, but open your pop up controller (in my case controllerB) and add the following lines before @interface:

```
@protocol PopUpControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)tourButtonTouched;

@end
```

in controllerB:

```
@interface YOUR_POPUP_CONTROLLER_CLASSNAME_OR_CLASS_B : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <PopUpControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

So in the controllerA you should have controllerB instance. Asign the delegate to the controllerA after allocation this instance in the memory:

```
controllerB.delegate = self;
```

Also you will need delegate callback implementation in controllerA class:

```
- (void)tourButtonTouched
{
// Here will be you code that push 3rd controller. Be sure that self (current) controller has navigation parent controller. Because in another push method will no work.

[self.navigationController pushViewController:IBTHirdViewController animated:YES];

// Use present if there is no navigation controller: [self presentViewController:IBTHirdViewController animated:YES];
}
```